# Present Tense and Future Tense

Tags: tense, present-tense, future-tense, sequence-of-tenses

The question, below, is in present tense but the answer, below in second clause, is in future tense. Why?

The question is " what does the headline suggest about the main idea of the article?".

The answer is "...it suggests that the article **will be** the difficulties faced by teachers.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you it is incorrect. *Will be* is in the future tense but the question is in present tense.

Correct answer:

> it suggests that the article **is about** the difficulties faced by teachers